# Изучение Qt с азов.

Tags: qt, c++

Фигачил в Дельфе/Билдере потом на долго пересел на .NET.
Но появилась перспектива проекта на Qt на никсах.
Порекомендуйте литературу в которых начинается с азов для новичков/дурачков до более серьезного.

Comment: Такой вопрос уже [задавался](http://hashcode.ru/questions/11605/qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Помимо перечисленного рекомендую [учебные материалы Nokia](http://qt.nokia.com/learning/education/course-materials/).

Comment: да я понимаю - но кажется я спросил немножко не то - может точнее бы следовало так спросить - литературу/документацию для разработки декстопных приложении под никсами для .NET разработчика.
т.е. идея в том что я - человек пришедший с "форточек" и .NET - хочу разрабатывать под никсами...

Comment: Разработка на Qt под Linux ничем не отличается от Windows -- в этом суть Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, начинающим Qt-шникам советуют Макса Шлее. Однако, на мой взгляд, тут лучше начать что-то писать и по ходу спрашивать у Qt-doc. Лично меня  Qt-шная справка очень порадовала.

Answer (score 2):

Для старта рекомендую [вот эти](http://habrahabr.ru/company/Nokia/blog/132006/) тренинги просмотреть. Мы собрали туда все вопросы, которые обычно возникают у новичков.